# How to expose an event from UIView to UIViewController

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a UIView with the following code:

```
import UIKit


class ServiceAuthHeaderViewController: UIView {


    @IBOutlet var lblHeaderTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var btnAddService: UIButton!

    class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        return UINib(nibName: "ServiceAuthHeaderView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    }

    @IBAction func onAddService(sender: AnyObject) {
        // I want other UIViewControllers to know when this event ocurrs

    }
}
```

Now I have a `UIViewController` where I create an instance of the UIView:

```
  var headerView = ServiceAuthHeaderViewController.instanceFromNib()
        headerView. // here I want to attach the onAddService event.
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside delegate and callbacks like what suggested by @fiks, you can also just simply use add target.

**Step 1:**
change the following to return a `ServiceAuthHeaderView` instead of a `UIView` so that you can access its `IBOutlet`. I renamed it to `ServiceAuthHeaderView` from `ServiceAuthHeaderViewController` as this is subclassing UIView.

```
class func instanceFromNib() -> ServiceAuthHeaderView {
    return UINib(nibName: "ServiceAuthHeaderView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! ServiceAuthHeaderView
}
```

**Step 2:** In your parent that subclass `UIViewController`, add the `btnAddService` target in `viewDidLoad`

```
class ServiceAuthViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      let headerView = ServiceAuthHeaderView.instanceFromNib()
      headerView.btnAddService.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ServiceAuthViewController.btnAddServicePressed(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
  }
}
```

**Step 3:** Create the target action that you entered in the selector and do what you need when the button is pressed inside it.

```
func btnAddServicePressed(button: UIButton) {
    print("Code for button pressed should be place here")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do it.

**Using Delegate pattern.**

You can create a protocol and then implement it in your view controller:

```
protocol ServiceAuthHeaderViewDelegate {
    func onAddService(sender: AnyObject)
}

class ServiceAuthHeaderView: UIView {
    var delegate: ServiceAuthHeaderViewDelegate?

    @IBOutlet var lblHeaderTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var btnAddService: UIButton!

    class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        return UINib(nibName: "ServiceAuthHeaderView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    }

    @IBAction func onAddService(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.onAddService(sender)
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, ServiceAuthHeaderViewDelegate {
    var myServiceAuthHeaderView: ServiceAuthHeaderView?

    // some initialization function
    func initViews() {
        myServiceAuthHeaderView?.delegate = self
    }

    func onAddService(sender: AnyObject) {
        // handling of the callback.
    }
}
```

**Using closures as callbacks**:

```
class ServiceAuthHeaderView: UIView {
    var onAddServiceCallback: ((sender: AnyObject) -> Void)?

    @IBOutlet var lblHeaderTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var btnAddService: UIButton!

    class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        return UINib(nibName: "ServiceAuthHeaderView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    }

    @IBAction func onAddService(sender: AnyObject) {
        onAddServiceCallback?(sender: sender)
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var myServiceAuthHeaderView: ServiceAuthHeaderView?

    // some initialization function
    func initViews() {
        myServiceAuthHeaderView?.onAddServiceCallback = { sender in
            // handling the callback
        }
    }
}
```

Both approaches are suitable. The second one requires less code though (no need to create additional protocol)